# Derivative of the measure of the set where $f > t$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a continuous function on a topological measure space $(X,\mu)$. Define $g(t) = \mu\{f \geq t\}$ for $t\in \mathbb R$. I am interested in the derivative of $g$. Is there a simple expression for it? What conditions on $f$ will ensure that it exists almost everywhere? What about everywhere?

Comment: Is there any simple expression for the derivative of $g$ in terms of $f$? This is the part I am most interested in.

Comment: It would be nice if you voted on the answers you receive (you don't ever seem to do that). They often involve a non-trivial amount of effort and a single mouse-click can't be too much to ask for.

Comment: When I posted the comment, the answer was accepted and had zero votes. Anyway, my point is: you've asked 48 questions most of which were answered and you cast 11 votes in total, which I find a bit ... minimalistic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the right question to ask is whether $g$ is [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity); this is equivalent to $g$ being almost everywhere diferentiable and equal to the integral of its derivative (i.e. the fundamental theorem of calculus holds).

(For a function which is not absolutely continuous, the derivative, even if it exists, is generally not very useful.  For an example with this property, take $X$ to be the Cantor set and $\mu$ the [Cantor measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_measure), and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ the inclusion function.  Then $g$ is the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), which is a.e. differentiable but whose derivative is zero.  You can't learn very much about this function from its derivative.)

In your setting, the function $g$ is absolutely continuous if and only if the push-forward measure $\mu \circ f^{-1}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure; that is, if for any $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ which has Lebesgue measure zero, we have $\mu(f^{-1}(A))=0$.  ([See Wikipedia for references.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Relation_between_the_two_notions_of_absolute_continuity))

Conditions on $f$ for this to hold can be a bit tricky and will probably require more structure.  For example, in the case where $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu$ is a nice smooth measure (e.g. Gaussian measure), a typical condition for $g$ to be absolutely continuous is that $f$ be (weakly) differentiable and $\nabla f \ne 0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.  (If $X$ is a Banach space and $\mu$ is a Gaussian measure, one can get the same result by means of the Malliavin calculus.)  Is there a particular setting you have in mind?

**Edit:** You ask about a formula for $g'$.  Let's suppose $X = \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mu$ is absolutely continuous to Lebesgue measure with $C^1$ density  $p$ (i.e. $d\mu = p dm$).  Also suppose $f$ is, say, $C^1$.  Then, at least formally, we have
$$g'(t) = \int_{\{f > t\}} \left(\nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|^2}\right) + \frac{\nabla f \cdot \nabla p}{|\nabla f|^2 p}\right)\,d\mu.$$

*Proof sketch.*  Let $\psi(t) = 1_{[a,b)}(t)$, so $\int_X \psi(f)\,d\mu = g(a) - g(b)$.  Set $\phi(s) = \int_{a}^s \psi(t)\,dt = \int_a^b 1_{\{s > t\}}\,dt$ so that $\phi' = \psi$, and note by the chain rule that $\nabla \phi(f) = \psi(f) \nabla f$.  We thus have
$$\psi(f) = \nabla \phi(f) \cdot \frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|^2}$$
and so
$$\begin{align*}
g(a) - g(b) &= \int_X \nabla \phi(f) \cdot \frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|^2}\,d\mu \\
&= \int_X \nabla \phi(f) \cdot \frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|^2}p \,dm \\
&= -\int_X \phi(f) \left(p \nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|^2}\right) + \nabla p \cdot \frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|^2}\right)\,dm \\
&= -\int_X \phi(f) \left(\nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|^2}\right) + \frac{\nabla p \cdot \nabla f}{|\nabla f|^2 p}\right)\,d\mu \end{align*}$$
where in the third line we used integration by parts.

If we write $h =   \left(\nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|^2}\right) + \frac{\nabla p \cdot \nabla f}{|\nabla f|^2 p}\right)$ for short, we have
$$\begin{align*} g(a) - g(b) &= -\int_X \phi(f) h\,d\mu \\
&= -\int_X \int_a^b 1_{\{f > t\}}\,dt\, h\,d\mu \\
&= -\int_a^b \int_X 1_{\{f > t\}} h \,d\mu\,dt  \end{align*}$$
by Fubini's theorem.  Now thanks to the fundamental theorem of calculus we are done.

Of course, one needs to check integrability conditions in several places to make this a real proof, but it does suggest that an essential feature will be that $|\nabla f|$ does not get too close to 0.  I don't know whether this is the kind of formula you are looking for; as I said it suggests that you will need more structure than just a topological measure space.

I took this proof from D. Nualart, *The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics*, Proposition 2.1.1.  (There it is in the context of Gaussian measure in infinite dimensions, but the idea is the same.)

Comment: Well done, Nate! Thanks, it contains a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T=\inf\{t\ge0:g(t)<+\infty\}$. Then $g$ is decreasing on $(T,+\infty)$, so that it is almost everywhere differentiable on that interval (see for instance [Theorem 14 in this post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/245a-notes-5-differentiation-theorems/) on Terry Tao's blog.) Observe that continuity is not needed.

As for everywhere differentiability, my impression is that it is a more difficult question.